# Exchange 2013 OWA/ECP redirect loop

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, exchange-2013

I have an issue with a fresh Exchange 2013 install on a 2K8r2 box that is fully updated as well as Exchange 2013 updated to CU3.

When attempting to access /owa or /ecp in Chrome, I get "This webpage has a redirect loop" ("Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS").  IE just breaks the connection and Firefox gives a similar error to Chrome.  This happens on HTTPS and HTTP, locally using FQDN and IP as well as remotely using FQDN and IP.  I have reset the OWA and ECP virtual directories and still have the same problem.  I have made sure there are no HTTP Redirects enabled on the sites or virtual sites.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This was caused by the default IIS user not being set to the appropriate IUSR user for various virtual directories and application pools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the default IIS user not being set to the appropriate IUSR user for various virtual directories and application pools.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you could provide the details in setting those "appropriate" settings.